# How to prepareForReuse on a UITableView with auto-layout?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have have a UITableView with cells of automatic dimension using auto-layout. In addition, all of the subviews of the cells are using auto-layout (programmatic constraints).

Since these cells and their corresponding subviews have uniquely different sizes, when they are reused, the constraints for the cell and subviews do not seem to invalidated and reset and this results in the following:

Demonstration of problem:

[Without reuse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBB_M2FqeJI)
[With reuse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwuho215ons)

I have tried all sorts of things in the prepareForReuse function but I haven't been able to reset all constraints. **How can this be achieved?**

Something I tried:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    
    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    removeConstraints(constraints)
    subviews.forEach( { $0.removeConstraints($0.constraints); $0.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()  })
    
    
    setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}
```

Comment: Still an x-y question, but much better than before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of situation is why there are multiple reuse buckets. Use a different cell subclass / reuse string for each *type* of cell. That way, there is nothing to do: just set up the cell once and let autolayout take care of resizing when, say, the text is different or (for an image cell) the image is different.

Comment: (I would suggest abandoning the use of `prepareForReuse`; personally I've never needed to use it for anything.)

Comment: I know devs that use it and like that approach. Like you, I tend to instead fully configure cells in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, that's why that part is a comment and not part of the answer.

Comment: All of my view configuration logic is inside of one cell class, can I use multiple reuse strings for the same class?

Comment: Yes, but that very question suggests you are a prisoner of your own architecture. You should rethink this. Isn’t this why we have subclasses? Protocols? Dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against deleting all your constraints and rebuilding them when getting a cell ready for reuse. Instead, I would add outlets to your constraints, and then either update their constants to change their sizing/spacing, or have them divided into sets for your different use-cases and use `activate(_:)` and `deactivate(_:)` to turn the different sets of constraints on/off. (Or a combination of adjusting constants and turning some constraints on and off.

It might also be simpler to set up different types of cells using different identifiers, and just set the constraints up on each type of when you create those cells. I'd make this my first choice, in fact.